# How to do a no-DNS site preview, when a wildcard redirect is in place

Tags: dns, cpanel, wordpress

I'm looking to figure out how to replicate the functionality of GoDaddy's PreviewDNS when I'm moving a site to my own web host based in cpanel.

My setup is this: I have a wordpress multiuser site setup with a subdomain install, and a wildcard redirect.

I can't figure out how I can preview the website for an account before the DNS is switched over to my host from the old host.

I've been able to *sorta* do this by creating an A record of a subdomain over to my host, but I still have the issue of not being able to test the actual files instead of a copy in a subdomain.

I have two IP addresses attached to the server, one to the server itself and all the shared domains, and the other dedicated to the WP multisite.

When I go to http://ipaddress/~username/, I either get an error, or get redirected to the wordpress multisite's default "this site doesn't exist, sign up now to create it" page. I've tried this with both IP addresses with no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is ensure that everything is working on the new server before having the DNS globally changed for all users? You could change your local computers hosts file to point the domain (and any subdomains you wish to test) over to the new dedicated IP address, which is essentially moving the DNS over for just yourself.

Here's a pretty good guide on how to do it: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect. Worked like a charm.